# Count distinct based on order of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing measurements, it looks like this:

```
SELECT [Plant] --plant name
       ,[Machine] --machine name
       ,[Material] --material name
       ,[Batch] --batch name
       ,[DMC] --data matrix code, each part has one
       ,[ProductionTime] --time stamp UTC
       ,[Result] --0/1 as NOK/OK
FROM [dbo].[Results]
```

Each row is one measurement, having a result. Each tested part has a DMC. Since parts can be tested several times, we have duplicated DMCs (with different results) in this table.

Example data:

| Plant | Machine | Material | Batch | DMC | ProductionTime | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | X | ABC | 2023-02-16 16:21:52 | 1 |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | X | DEF | 2023-02-16 16:21:30 | 1 |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | X | DEF | 2023-02-16 16:21:09 | 0 |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | Y | GHI | 2023-02-16 16:20:47 | 1 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialA | X | JKL | 2023-02-16 16:20:24 | 0 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialB | Y | MNO | 2023-02-16 16:20:03 | 1 |

To calculate the **scrap rate**, I need to count the amount of OK and NOK parts.
For #OKParts, conditions are:
-#OKParts: for each DMC, consider its **latest **production time and calculate how many rows have result = 1
(-#NOKParts same but result = 0)

Additionally for calculating **FTT-Yield** ("first time through"):
-#PartsFirstTestOK: for each DMC, consider its **oldest** production time and calculate how many rows have result = 1
(-#PartsFirstTestNOK: same but result = 0)

Since this table is very big, I need to reduce the amount of data by filtering the table (see below the where statement) and group the results.

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT [Plant]
      ,[Machine]
      ,[Material]
      ,[Batch]
      ,Count([Result]) as '#Tests' --all rows
      ,Count(Distinct [DMC]) as '#Parts' --all different DMCs
      ,COUNT(CASE when [Result] = 1 THEN 1 END) as '#OKTests'
      ,COUNT(CASE when [Result] = 0 THEN 1 END) as '#NOKTests'
  FROM table
  where [Plant] = 'A' and [ProductionTime] > DATEADD(DAY, -365,GETDATE())
  group by [Plant],[Material],[Batch],[Machine]
```

*(Sum(Cast([Result] as INT)) and Count([Result])-Sum(Cast([Result] as INT)) instead of the CASE functions would also work here)*

To get (as now) the following result:

| Plant | Machine | Material | Batch | #Tests | #Parts | #OKTests | #NOKTests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | X | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | Y | 124 | 96 | 93 | 31 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialA | X | 11 | 9 | 9 | 2 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialB | Y | 21 | 13 | 11 | 10 |

and I want to add this table by columns #OKParts, #NOKParts, #PartsFirstTestOK, #PartsFirstTestNOK.

I've tried to create a sub-query, FIRST_VALUE & OVER function, but none of them worked for me. I am quite a starter in SQL.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses windowed ROW_NUMBER() functions to assign both ascending and descending sequence numbers to the series of tests for a given part. Checking for one or the other value = 1 can be used to limit your counts to just the first or last test.

```
SELECT Plant
      ,Machine
      ,Material
      ,Batch
      ,Count(Result) as [#Tests] --all rows
      ,Count(Distinct DMC) as [#Parts] --all different DMCs
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN 1 END) as [#OKTests]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 0 THEN 1 END) as [#NOKTests]
      ,COUNT(CASE when RowNumAsc = 1 AND Result = 1 THEN 1 END) as [#PartsFirstTestOK]
      ,COUNT(CASE when RowNumAsc = 1 AND Result = 0 THEN 1 END) as [#PartsFirstTestNOK]
      ,COUNT(CASE when RowNumDesc = 1 AND Result = 1 THEN 1 END) as [#OKParts]
      ,COUNT(CASE when RowNumDesc = 1 AND Result = 0 THEN 1 END) as [#NOKParts]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Plant, Material, Batch, Machine, DMC
            ORDER BY ProductionTime
            ) AS RowNumAsc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Plant, Material, Batch, Machine, DMC
            ORDER BY ProductionTime DESC
            ) AS RowNumDesc
    FROM table1
) T
where Plant = 'A' and ProductionTime > DATEADD(DAY, -365,GETDATE())
group by Plant, Material, Batch, Machine;
```

Sample results:

| Plant | Machine | Material | Batch | #Tests | #Parts | #OKTests | #NOKTests | #PartsFirstTestOK | #PartsFirstTestNOK | #OKParts | #NOKParts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | X | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialA | X | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| A | MachineA | MaterialA | Y | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | MachineB | MaterialB | Y | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kztMXoHG) for a working demo.

Comment: Could someone with edit access kindly paste the SQL code from the fiddle into the above post? I'm getting blocked.

Comment: I have updated everything :)
Please let me know, if anything else I can help you with